# Execute static method in multithreads

Tags: c#

Suppose I have a class like below:

```
public static class Foo
{
    public static int Do(int original)
    {
        int result=original + 1;
        return result;
    }
}

public class Bar
{
    public void Invoke()
    {
        int result=Foo.Do(1);
    }
}
```

Anyone can tell me how it be invoked in CLR? All we know that CLR is a virtual machine base on stack. An instance which would invoke Foo.Do() method has its own Call Stack. It push a int arg to Stack , and then call Foo.Do() method. I'm woudering whether few instances in multithreads invoke Foo.Do() would disturb each others? Every instance has a copy of Foo.Do() or rather?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each thread has its own call stack set up. So when you call a function in one thread, the stack is changed *only for that thread*. Other threads can call whatever other functions they want, without affecting each other (aside from shared state, but that's another issue. The important thing is that the stack isn't shared).

Answer (score 1):

> I'm woudering whether few instances in multithreads invoke Foo.Do() would disturb each others? Every instance has a copy of Foo.Do() or rather?

In this case, each instance would be fine.  There is no data shared between the separate threads, since `Invoke` and `Foo.Do` do not rely on any other shared state.

The main issues with multiple threads occur when you're trying to share data between the individual threads.  At that point, you need to take care to synchronize the access to the shared data.

Answer (score 0):

Perphas you should look at [ThreadLocal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642243.aspx) API so you can have a thread specific storage. In your case as Reed suggested, it should not matter as there is no shared state but if there is any, it will matter as static storage is shared between threads until unless it is ThreadLocal